# Why does as.numeric not work?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame `senti` as:

```
p p p p
p p p p
p p p p
```

I change a column of `senti`(a col of "n"), and I try to change each p into 1, so I write the code as:

```
senti[,4] <- data$Category
senti[senti=="p"] <- 1
 senti[senti=="n"] <- -1
```

Then, it is not a number 1, so I try to convert it into number:

```
> senti<-as.numeric(senti)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> senti[1,1]<-as.numeric(senti[1,1])
> senti[1,1]+senti[1,1]
Error in senti[1, 1] + senti[1, 1] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

but, it does not work, I do not understand why. I suppose there maybe some set of the original matrix, but my code is too long to paste all of them here. Is anyone can help?

Comment: A matrix can only contain a single type.

Comment: To followup Dason's note: switch to a `data.frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first say you have a data frame, then say you have a matrix ... which is it? Your second attempt was convert a single cell to numeric, but you can't have a mixed column in a data.frame. You need to convert the whole column at once

```
senti[,1:4] <- sapply(senti[,1:4], as.numeric)
```

It may also be possible that one of the columns is a list, what does `str(senti)` give? You may need to unlist that column first.

Comment: `Error: (list) object cannot ...` does hint of columns possibly being of type `list`

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the result by:

```
senti <- read.table(text="p p p n
p p p n
p p p n",sep="",header=F)

 senti[] <- c(1,-1)[unlist(senti)]

 str(senti)
 #'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
 #$ V1: num  1 1 1
 #$ V2: num  1 1 1
 #$ V3: num  1 1 1
 #$ V4: num  -1 -1 -1
```